# PubNub SubscribeCallback error

Tags: android, crash, android-arrayadapter, pubnub

I tried to create chat application using PubNub. But if e trying to add message text to ArrayAdapter it crashes. 
On successCallback it only calls AdaptAdd with message
This is code of it:

```
public void AdaptAdd(String m) {
    adp.add(m);
}
```

And this is log output:

```
12-11 16:00:22.791 7206 7231 D PubNub [1,"Subscribe connected","14498279037104566"]
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: Subscribe-Manager-136126964-3
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime Process: com.redline.ichat, PID: 7206
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6556)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:3034)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:761)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:761)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:761)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:761)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime  at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:10555)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at android.view.View.setFocusableInTouchMode(View.java:7502)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:737)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:832)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:6179)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(ArrayAdapter.java:301)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(ArrayAdapter.java:197)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at com.redline.ichat.MainActivity.AdaptAdd(MainActivity.java:93)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at com.redline.ichat.MainActivity$100000000.successCallback(MainActivity.java:52)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at com.pubnub.api.Callback.successWrapperCallback(Unknown Source)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at com.pubnub.api.PubnubCore.invokeSubscribeCallback(Unknown Source)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at com.pubnub.api.PubnubCore.access$1100(Unknown Source)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at com.pubnub.api.PubnubCore$14.handleResponse(Unknown Source)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at com.pubnub.api.SubscribeWorker.process(Unknown Source)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at com.pubnub.api.Worker.run(Unknown Source)
12-11 16:00:24.284 7206 7231 E AndroidRuntime at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-11 16:00:24.655 7206 7232 E Surface getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab43c300
```

Comment: from the stacktrace seems that the callback is called by a background thread.

Comment: I don't think the title seems very fair to PubNub. Not a PubNub issue as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant access views from a background thread.
You can use this code to check how they are using the `notifyUser()` to do things on main thread
https://github.com/pubnub/java/blob/master/android/examples/PubnubExample/src/com/pubnub/examples/pubnubExample10/MainActivity.java